# How to load a java web app in the terminal?

Tags: java, tomcat, groovy, terminal

I have a java web app developed on Struts and deployed on a Tomcat server. I want to run commands and use the functions of the app using the console - something like in 'rails console' such that even if the server was not running, the entire app environment is loaded and the app is usable from the terminal itself. 
I have tried Grails (Groovy) but couldn't figure out how to interface the java app with it as 'grails console' works for app developed on Grails. 
How to go about doing this?

Comment: have you packaged your web app as WAR or EAR ?

Comment: The app is deployed as a WAR file.

Comment: "such that even if the server was not running, the entire app environment is loaded", that would mean an existing servlet context environment, thus a running server. You can embedd Tomcat or Jetty into your project, or just create a main method, to call services which do not rely on a servlet context.

Comment: You mean like the [CRaSH shell](http://www.crashub.org/)?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514856/gradle-run-multiple-webapps-with-jetty